# Groovy findAll() on List<List> giving errors

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to run a code and stuck in a piece of code which I found was rather simple:

```
List<List> nearestAvailableEmployees = Staffing.createCriteria().list {
    createAlias('employee','e')
    projections {
        property('e.id')
        property('e.name')
        property('endDate')
        property('startDate')
    }
    gt('endDate', new Date())
    and{
        order("e.id", "asc")
        order("endDate", "asc")

       }
}

return nearestAvailableEmployees.findAll{
    it[0] == 112
 }
```

While running the above code I get the following error and I am not getting the reason for it.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
Script1$_run_closure2.doCall() is applicable for argument types: 
(java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp) values:
[5, Aditee Chatterjee, 2013-12-27 00:00:00.0, ...]
Possible solutions: doCall(), call(), doCall(java.lang.Object), findAll()
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:26)
at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleService.eval(ConsoleService.groovy:57)
at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleService.eval(ConsoleService.groovy:37)
at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleController$_closure2.doCall(ConsoleController.groovy:61)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) undefined
```

I rectified the error by modifying the code and adding the following segment of code just after the criteria query:

```
.collect{
    it as List
}
```

Can anybody help me with the code.

Comment: What version of Grails?  I just tried it with 2.3.3 and it works.  Maybe print out `nearestAvailableEmployees.dump()` and see what datatype you're getting back from `list`?

Comment: I am using Grails Version 2.1.1
and the datatype I am getting is ArrayList after printing what you said.

Comment: It should work then...  Are you sure that's all your code?

Comment: Yup, I am sure that's all the code Have got. I can send you screenshot if you insist

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
List<List> nearestAvailableEmployees = Staffing.createCriteria().list {
...
}
```

you get a list of Staffing objects, not a list of lists.
Note that Generics in Groovy are good maybe for code readability, but have no impact even in compile time (which is different from Java) as proved by the fact that your code compiles successfully.

So you can change find closure to:

```
return nearestAvailableEmployees.findAll{
    // it is of type Staffing 
    it.id == 112
}
```

or to emphasize that nearestAvailableEmployees is a list of Staffing objects:

```
return nearestAvailableEmployees.findAll{
    Staffing staffing ->

    staffing.id == 112
}
```

Comment: I will not get a list of staffing objects because I am using PROJECTIONS which will give me selected fields which are indeed object.